# How to select a particular value in row from a table in html

Tags: jquery, html, jinja2

[it is something like this where i check 1st button i can get the January month savngs which are in a text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCeTF.jpg) Hi all im planning to create a table as follows it contains a check box in the first column of each row upon checking that check box i must send the path attribute to "next" url byu clicking on submit button how can i do it??

```
    <form action="/next" method="post">
    <table cellspacing="25" align ="center">
    <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Name</td>
        <td>Path</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
      {% for obj in obj_list %}
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="insta" value="">
     <td>{{ obj._id }}</td>
     <td>{{ obj.name }}</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="path" value="{{ obj._path }}" disabled="disabled" ></td>
     <td>{{ obj.date }}</td>
        {% end %}
    </table>
   </div>
   <div id="send">
   <input type="submit"  value="Send">
  </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Use form `method="GET"`

Comment: ohkk from there on how to proceed??? @Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add JQuery if not added and try this, 
Add this js function

```
function changeUrl(clickedChk)
     {
        if( $(clickedChk).is(":checked") )
        {
            var path = $($(clickedChk).closest("tr").find("input[type=text]")[0]).val();
            $("#myform").prop("action",path);
        }
     }
```

change your html little bit like below

```
    <form id="myform" action="/next" method="post">
    <table cellspacing="25" align ="center">
    <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
        <td>Path</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>

      {% for obj in obj_list %}
     <tr>
         <td><input onclick="changeUrl(this)" type="checkbox" name="insta" value="">
         <td>{{ obj._id }}</td>
         <td>{{ obj.name }}</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="path" ></td>
         <td>{{ obj.date }}</td>
     </tr>
        {% end %}
    </table>
   </div>
   <div id="send">
   <input type="submit"  value="Start">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the form to be auto-submitted when user clicks a checkbox, I suggest the following -

```
<form action="/next" method="post" id="myForm">
    <table cellspacing="25" align ="center">
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Path</td>
            <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
        {% for obj in obj_list %}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="insta" value="{{ obj._path }}" onchange="document.getElementById("myForm").submit();" >
                <!-- Object path is added as value for checkbox and as soon as checkbox is checked, the form is submitted -->
                <td>{{ obj._id }}</td>
                <td>{{ obj.name }}</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="path" value="{{ obj._path }}" disabled="disabled" ></td>
                <td>{{ obj.date }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% end %}
    </table>
    <div id="send">
        <input type="submit"  value="Start">
    </div>
</form>
```